# Refinement Template for Choice Fields (Yes/No)

Tags: choice-field, refinement-panel

I added a custom search result page, which offers custom refinement options. One of these options include refinement by matching a Choice (Yes/No) field. The refinement is using the default Refinement Item template, and looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the mapped property's values (Yes/No) are displayed in binary.
Is there a way of displaying *Yes* and *No* instead of 1 and 0? Or even better - *Online* and *Offline*?

Comment: I don't think that's "binary" - it is probably the value of SQL Server's bit data type field for this data.

Comment: Clearly, but how can I map these fields to Strings? (Online/Offline)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think its possible with OOB implementation. You will have to do small customization in Refinement Display Template.

Open your site in SharePoint Designer (*Or whatever editor you like to open display templates*), go to `Master Pages > Display Templates > Filters`. Copy "Filter_Default.html" and open to add some custom code.

You will need following code to be added in function `outputFilter`.

```
var origOnlineOffline = refinementName;
var formattedOnlineOffline = '';
// Sometimes get an "All" setting in order to remove the refiner,
// so need to leave this alone.
if (origOnlineOffline == 'All') {
    formattedOnlineOffline = origOnlineOffline;
}
else {
    new Boolean(refinementName);
    formattedOnlineOffline = origOnlineOffline == 1 ? 'Online' : 'Offline';
}
```

And following line of change in HTML Div

```
<div id='RefinementName' class='_#= nameClass =#_'> _#= $htmlEncode(formattedOnlineOffline) =#_ </div>
```

After saving the new display template, return to search page, edited the page, and edit the Refiners webpart. After selecting the refiner you want to change, choose new display template (*the one you created above*).

I have referred [The Story of the Boolean Search Refiner](https://lifeofaprogrammergirl.wordpress.com/2015/01/26/the-story-of-the-boolean-search-refiner/). I recommend you to read this blog, Nice one.